# htpasswd sets incorrect password when the password has special characters

Tags: linux, bash, password, htpasswd

**The Problem**
I am attempting to update passwords for a large list of users using `htpasswd`. I am using a csv file to pull in the new passwords.
When the script runs it appears to successfully update the users. However, users are unable to log in using their new passwords.
here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Bash to update passwords from csv
CSV=intranet_users.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $CSV ] && { echo "$CSV file not found"; exit 99; }
  while read name dept username password
   do
     if [ "${username}" != '#N/A' ] && [ "${username}" != 0 ]; then
        echo "Resetting password for $username to: ${password}"
        htpasswd -b /path/to/passwdFile $username '${password}'
     fi
   done < $CSV
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

If I run the script against a test csv with no special characters in the passwords, it works.
If I run `htpasswd -b /path/to/passwdFile username 'password'` on the command line (passwords with special chars), everything works as it should.

**Why does the script fail to set the password correctly?**

**What I have tried**
I have tried running htpasswd using `eval`
I have tried various methods of quoting $password i.e "'", '\'', "\'"

Comment: Replace the problematic characters in the CSV file. And don't generate such passwords on the first place.

Comment: try read -r and using htpasswd -b /path/to/passwdFile "$username" "${password}", maybe.

Comment: Do you have some examples of intranet_users.csv containing problematic characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting in hope of helping someone.

It turns out the problem was not with the script. The csv file was not clean.

The csv was generated from Excel in a Windows environment. The file had dos line endings - \r

I added the line below before the line that calls htpasswd
`password="${password/$'\r'/}"`
Here's the working code:

```
CSV=intranet_users.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $CSV ] && { echo "$CSV file not found"; exit 99; }
while read name dept username password
do
    if [ "${username}" != '#N/A' ] && [ "${username}" != 0 ]; then
       password="${password/$'\r'/}"
       echo "Resetting password for $username to: $password"
       htpasswd -b /path/to/passwdFile $username ${password}
    fi
done < $CSV
IFS=$OLDIFS
```